# How to get orientation in an alarm receiver?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, screen-orientation, android-alarms

Sorry new to coding and not sure if I am asking the correct question. I searched on here and couldn't find a solution, so I don't think I am asking a duplicate question.

I have set up an alarm receiver that sends a notification and I am trying to get the device orientation using:

```
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    // In landscape
} else {
    // In portrait
}
```

but it is giving me the warning:

```
Cannot resolve method 'getResources'
```

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to access getResources method for your application by using the Context object inside the onReceive method of your receiver.